# I want to "tweak" the positioning of a short Bootstrap "Radio-Inline" snippet

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a simple radio-inline snippet based upon Bootstrap 5.

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 form-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="radio-inline">
          :::
          :::
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          :::
          :::
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          :::
          :::
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do:

- Centre the three radio-inline items in the form-container
- Add space between each of the three radio-inline items.

I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: Please show your actual code, instead of ASCII art. [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. The changes I made are:

1. Added `text-center` class to the form-container to center the items
2. Added `col-md-12` instead of `col-md-6` class so that the contents get the 12 columns (entire width)
3. Added `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` for making the space between each of the three radio-inline items.

A suggestion: Next time, provide the codes in the first instance with all the necessary details so that everyone can easily understand and provide you a solution instead of downvoting your question.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-3 form-container text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline d-flex justify-content-between">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                :::
                :::
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                :::
                :::
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                :::
                :::
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Islam, for taking the time to read and then compose an answer to my question.  I appreciate you for this. However, I do have an additional question:  You mentioned a hint "Next time, provide the codes in the first instance with all the necessary details so that everyone can easily understand ...".  I do not understand what you mean? What would be the improvement that I should apply?

Comment: You are most welcome :) If it helps then you can upvote the answer and mark it as the "Accepted Answer" if you want.

Comment: In the first time you didn't provide the codes, just showed this "::: ::: :::".  So other users were not interested to give an answer and downvoted your question because of the lack of details. But if you have provided that codes in the beginning then that wouldn't have happened. So if you can follow that in future then it will not happen again :)